# Pandas calculate year over year (or any other index) change in rows

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Say I have a DataFrame as such:

```
            A    B  C  D
           ---  -- -- -- 
2012-01-01 AAA  11 22 33
2013-01-01 AAA  11 23 53
2014-01-01 AAA  11 78 96  
2012-01-01 BBB  12 42 24
2013-01-01 BBB  13 97 91
2014-01-01 BBB  14 25 12
```

(index is datetime)

I want to figure out the change in column C between the first appearance of AAA and the last (in this case 78-22 = 56). Currently I am doing this by pivoting the table so the years are columns across the top and adding a difference column. Is there a better way to do this without modifying the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If A has many groups, you may consider using `groupby`. Assume `df` is the DataFrame to work with.

```
a = df.groupby("A")["C"]
newt = a.last() - a.first() 
print(newt)
```

The result:

```
A
AAA    56
BBB   -17
Name: C, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I do have many groups, is `last` and `first` a Pandas idiom or a Python one? I've never seen it and can't find it in the docs.

Comment: @RedRaven it belongs to Pandas. The `Groupby` object has these methods. For your reference: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following which does not modify the table.

```
import pandas as pd

#%% create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(index=['2012-01-01','2013-01-01','2014-01-01','2012-01-01','2013-01-01','2014-01-01',])
df['A'] = ['AAA','AAA','AAA','BBB','BBB','BBB'] 
df['C'] = [22, 23, 78, 42, 97, 25]
print(df)

#%% do the calculation
first_AAA = df.loc[(df['A']=='AAA'), 'C'].values[0]
last_AAA = df.loc[(df['A']=='AAA'), 'C'].values[-1]
Your_answer = last_AAA-first_AAA

#%% possibly slightly faster
AAA = df.loc[(df['A']=='AAA'), 'C'].values
Your_answer = AAA[-1]-AAA[0]
```

More about indexing can be found here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html